# Determining weather user entered GPS coordinate, or a street address

Tags: java, android

Im trying to use google maps for getting directions from my app.

The user can enter either an address or a GPS coordinate, and then when they click a button i call google maps app using intent, then pass it the stuff the user typed in so that google maps can giv them the directions to it.

Below shows getting directions from where the user is now, to GPS coordinates shown below

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
    Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=20.543,45.345"));
startActivity(intent);
```

But it seems the google maps API needs to know weather to navigate to an address, or a coordinate, how do i determine if the user typed in a street address or a coordinate so as to properly format the intent, or can i just pass whatever they typed to google maps and it will figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `regular expression` to check if the user punched in coordinates or street name.